# Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita"

Tags: archlinux, kde-plasma

This text shows up in `intellij idea`'s run tab. What is it? I searched in google but there were only gnome solutions. I'm using archlinux and kde5 plasma

Answer (score 13):

Running:

`sudo pacman -S gnome-themes-extra`

should install the missing theme.

Answer (score -1):

For Kubuntu 20.04 this worked for me (had this error when trying to run JavaFX app):

```
sudo apt install gnome-themes-standard
```

Comment: This isn't going to help, given the question comes from someone who clearly states they're using archlinux

Comment: I think is question was in google top, so other distro users will eventually find it